Heltec LoRa wireless stick and BME688 sensor
I'm trying to send sensor data from BME680 sensor using a Heltec Wireless Stick Lite v3 using LoRa. The code runs fine and the messages are sent, but I keep getting an error

BSEC warning code: 14

which looks like it has something to do with the sensor data, as all sent data are zeros.
My code is as follows; I really appreciate any help here as I can't figure out the problem:
#define MINIMUM_DELAY 30 // Minimum delay in seconds

#define HELTEC_WIRELESS_STICK_LITE
#include <heltec_unofficial.h>
#include <LoRaWAN_ESP32.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <bsec2.h>

void checkBsecStatus(Bsec2 bsec);
void newDataCallback(const bme68xData data, const bsecOutputs outputs, Bsec2 bsec);

Bsec2 envSensor;
LoRaWANNode* node;
RTC_DATA_ATTR uint8_t count = 0;

// Variables to store sensor data
float iaq, raw_temperature, raw_pressure, raw_humidity, raw_gas, stabilization_status, run_in_status;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println("setup");
  heltec_setup();
  Wire.begin(47, 48);
  while (!Serial) delay(10);

  bsecSensor sensorList[] = {
    BSEC_OUTPUT_IAQ, BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_TEMPERATURE, BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_PRESSURE,
    BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_HUMIDITY, BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_GAS, BSEC_OUTPUT_STABILIZATION_STATUS,
    BSEC_OUTPUT_RUN_IN_STATUS
  };

  if (!envSensor.begin(BME68X_I2C_ADDR_HIGH, Wire)) {
    checkBsecStatus(envSensor);
  }

  if (!envSensor.updateSubscription(sensorList, ARRAY_LEN(sensorList), BSEC_SAMPLE_RATE_LP)) {
    checkBsecStatus(envSensor);
  }

  envSensor.attachCallback(newDataCallback);

  Serial.println("BSEC library version " + String(envSensor.version.major) +
                 "." + String(envSensor.version.minor) + "." +
                 String(envSensor.version.major_bugfix) + "." +
                 String(envSensor.version.minor_bugfix));

  // Initialize radio
  Serial.println("Radio init");
  int16_t state = radio.begin();
  if (state != RADIOLIB_ERR_NONE) {
    Serial.println("Radio did not initialize. We'll try again later.");
    goToSleep();
  }

  node = persist.manage(&radio);
  if (!node->isActivated()) {
    Serial.println("Could not join network. We'll try again later.");
    goToSleep();
  }

  if (!envSensor.run()) {
    checkBsecStatus(envSensor);
  }

  // Prepare the payload
  uint8_t uplinkData[14];
  int iaq_int = iaq * 100; // Convert to int by multiplying by 100
  int temp_int = raw_temperature * 100;
  int press_int = raw_pressure;
  int hum_int = raw_humidity * 100;
  int gas_int = raw_gas;
  int stab_status_int = stabilization_status * 100;
  int run_in_status_int = run_in_status * 100;

  uplinkData[0] = iaq_int >> 8;
  uplinkData[1] = iaq_int;
  uplinkData[2] = temp_int >> 8;
  uplinkData[3] = temp_int;
  uplinkData[4] = press_int >> 8;
  uplinkData[5] = press_int;
  uplinkData[6] = hum_int >> 8;
  uplinkData[7] = hum_int;
  uplinkData[8] = gas_int >> 8;
  uplinkData[9] = gas_int;
  uplinkData[10] = stab_status_int >> 8;
  uplinkData[11] = stab_status_int;
  uplinkData[12] = run_in_status_int >> 8;
  uplinkData[13] = run_in_status_int;

  uint8_t downlinkData[256];
  size_t lenDown = sizeof(downlinkData);

  state = node->sendReceive(uplinkData, sizeof(uplinkData), 1, downlinkData, &lenDown);
  if (state == RADIOLIB_ERR_NONE || state == RADIOLIB_LORAWAN_NO_DOWNLINK) {
    Serial.println("Message sent");
  } else {
    Serial.printf("sendReceive returned error %d, we'll try again later.\n", state);
  }

  goToSleep();
}

void newDataCallback(const bme68xData data, const bsecOutputs outputs, Bsec2 bsec) {
  if (!outputs.nOutputs) {
    return;
  }

  Serial.println("BSEC outputs:\n\ttimestamp = " +
                 String((int)(outputs.output[0].time_stamp / INT64_C(1000000))));
  for (uint8_t i = 0; i < outputs.nOutputs; i++) {
    const bsecData output = outputs.output[i];
    switch (output.sensor_id) {
      case BSEC_OUTPUT_IAQ:
        iaq = output.signal;
        Serial.println("\tiaq = " + String(iaq));
        Serial.println("\tiaq accuracy = " + String((int)output.accuracy));
        break;
      case BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_TEMPERATURE:
        raw_temperature = output.signal;
        Serial.println("\ttemperature = " + String(raw_temperature));
        break;
      case BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_PRESSURE:
        raw_pressure = output.signal;
        Serial.println("\tpressure = " + String(raw_pressure));
        break;
      case BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_HUMIDITY:
        raw_humidity = output.signal;
        Serial.println("\thumidity = " + String(raw_humidity));
        break;
      case BSEC_OUTPUT_RAW_GAS:
        raw_gas = output.signal;
        Serial.println("\tgas resistance = " + String(raw_gas));
        break;
      case BSEC_OUTPUT_STABILIZATION_STATUS:
        stabilization_status = output.signal;
        Serial.println("\tstabilization status = " + String(stabilization_status));
        break;
      case BSEC_OUTPUT_RUN_IN_STATUS:
        run_in_status = output.signal;
        Serial.println("\trun in status = " + String(run_in_status));
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }
  }
}

void checkBsecStatus(Bsec2 bsec) {
  if (bsec.status < BSEC_OK) {
    Serial.println("BSEC error code : " + String(bsec.status));
  } else if (bsec.status > BSEC_OK) {
    Serial.println("BSEC warning code : " + String(bsec.status));
  }

  if (bsec.sensor.status < BME68X_OK) {
    Serial.println("BME68X error code : " + String(bsec.sensor.status));
  } else if (bsec.sensor.status > BME68X_OK) {
    Serial.println("BME68X warning code : " + String(bsec.sensor.status));
  }
}

void loop() {
  // Not used, as we enter deep sleep after setup
}

void goToSleep() {
  Serial.println("Going to deep sleep now");
  persist.saveSession(node);
  uint32_t interval = node->timeUntilUplink();
  uint32_t delayMs = max(interval, (uint32_t)MINIMUM_DELAY * 1000);
  Serial.printf("Next TX in %i s\n", delayMs / 1000);
  delay(100); // So message prints
  heltec_deep_sleep(delayMs / 1000);
}

